# How can we delete a particular screen view from Google analytics screen view list?

Tags: android, google-analytics, screen

I integrated google analytics to my android app. By mistake I sent some wrong screen views. Is there any way to delete that screen view from Google Analytics? Can anyone please help?

Comment: No way (other than deleting the view/property/account which of course will also delete any other data). Easiest way is to build a segment that excludes those screen views.

Comment: you can delete the Activity screen from your app manually, but from Google Analytics you are not allowed to do that rather than what @Eike said.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to delete the screen views. But you can use filters in either google analytics dashboard or in the API you use to fetch the data.